# Data Storage Method for Fast and Organized Query

Tags: python, sql, database, dataframe

I'm an adept deep learning computer science who's a bit new at finance. I am currently attempting to scrape Yahoo for 10-minute data for 505 stocks of SPX. In total, I'm going to get around 20k rows of floating-point data daily. Of course, data is the new oil so this will get super unmanageable quickly with such large amounts of data if I don't construct a correct process. As this is my first time constructing a dataset from scratch, I am completely lost as to whether I am doing it right and am seeking advice or solution.

The way I am going to process and store and then query the data is the following:

1. Get 20k data of the day
2. Convert 20k data into one csv / npz / pkl and save it in a folder and name it by the date
3. In another script, read all csv / npz / pkl that falls between certain days
4. Compile the tickers needed
5. Save as separate csv / npz / pkl

The main killer in this process would be the query system with so many files per day.

Someone advised me to use SQL or other large database languages but I'm not sure why it would be as or more efficient as this method. It would be great if someone also shares their method of constructing large databases or share some resources on good practices.

Edit: Below would be one entry of the csv in the daily data. It's tab-delimited:

```
NCLH    Sat Jun  6 14:44:29 2020    22.43   23.37   1000    23.43   800 109665301
```

Comment: That's not exactly a lot of data.  In any case you can use SQLite to dump your data into and then select from it for whatever date ranges you wish and proceed.  Probably the best way to continually update something such as this.

Comment: What is the limit in which SQLite becomes difficult to use? After 1 year, I would have around 252 * 20 = 5 million data points. Would SQLite still be able to handle it?

Comment: Also, does SQLite also read all the data into RAM? This may cause issues in the foreseeable future. The best-case scenario is a process where it reads from disk instead. I can put up with the slower speed.